# Поиск подсказки на изображении под разные разрешения

Tags: python, c++, opencv, распознавание-символов, компьютерное-зрение

В общем, стоит задача искать всплывающие подсказки в игре([пример подсказки](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ja35T.jpg), [пример скриншота](https://imgur.com/a/sRFxdri)). Реализовал через **templateMatching**, работает хорошо, но когда дело доходит до других разрешений этот вариант уже не такой хороший. Пробовал **ORB** но работает не очень(возможно я неправильно настроил), ещё пробовал простой поиск по контурам, но он цепляет слишком много лишнего текста на изображении, т.к на скриншоте присутствует HUD игры. Думал использовать **TesseractOCR**, да только на низких разрешениях он тоже ломается, и работает довольно медленно

Пока самый лучший метод что я нашёл это изменять размер шаблонов под новое разрешение, но это работает только для одного соотношения сторон то есть 16:9, в котором я вырезал само уведомление. Может стоит как-то адаптировать под новые соотношения сторон? Или есть метод получше?

Метод для поиска шаблонов использую самый обычный, а для других разрешений просто вычисляю насколько больше или меньше изображение и использую resize.

С++

```
//Изменение размера под новое разрешение
double scaleWidth = 1280 / 1920.0;
double scaleHeight = 720.0 / 1080.0;
int newWidth = round(templateForResize.cols * scaleWidth);
int newHeight = round(templateForResize.rows * scaleHeight);

cv::Mat resizedTemplate;
cv::resize(templateForResize, resizedTemplate, cv::Size(newWidth, newHeight), 0, 0, INTER_AREA);

//Поиск шаблона
bool FindObject(Mat& templateForFind, Mat& screenshot, Point& maxLoc, Mat& result, bool debug, double confid) {
    matchTemplate(screenshot, templateForFind, result, TM_CCOEFF_NORMED);
    double minVal, maxVal;
    minMaxLoc(result, &minVal, &maxVal, NULL, &maxLoc);

    if (debug) {
        std::cout << maxVal << std::endl;
    }

    if (maxVal >= confid) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Судя по всему, у вас подсказка всегда будет внизу экрана. Этого уже достаточно. Мы должны понять где будет расположена подсказка при любом разрешении (Координаты). Можно даже просто примерно посчитать "соотношение" для 16:9, сделать его чуть больше и и потом уже адаптировать это к остальным. И все. Искать в этом прямоугольнике, а он не большой и уже без match можно.

Comment: @Mister_Jesus, Здравствуйте, способ интересный, но немного не понял про то что не нужно будет использовать match. Вы имеете ввиду сравнивать вручную пиксели?

Comment: У вас задача найти подсказки - match уже не нужен, так как вы нашли фиксированное место, где они есть. Далее уже простой метод с помощью контура всё решит.

Comment: @Mister_Jesus, Понял вас, спасибо за отклик, обязательно попробую!